# Edit Style for multiple text

Tags: html, css

I know `<span>` can be used to mark the text I want to style but what if I want to do something like: make all word "the" red or make some of the texts blue and others green? Is there a simple way to do it?

```css
h1,
p {
  color: red;
}
span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <h3>This is Title 1</h3>
  <p>Enterprise networks are <span>becoming more complex every day</span>. As you spend more time and resources keeping the network up and running, it gets tough to develop and prepare for new markets or products. It’s time to make the switch to managed network
    services.</p>
  <p>Access this white paper to discover the <span>key benefits</span> of managed network services and learn how to stay in control of your network at the same time.</p>
</ul>
```

Comment: You will need JavaScript or jQuery for that

Comment: On a side note, your HTML is invalid.

Comment: You can create a class for the color style.

Comment: @Sidsec9 jQuery is JavaScript :)

Comment: @divinecomedian, I'm aware of that :) Was just giving a simplified option

Comment: I agree with @Sidsec9.  Use JavaScript to search for the words and wrap in `span`s with appropriate classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class to style this.
Example:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<h3>This is Title 1</h3>
    <p>Enterprise networks are <span class="green">becoming more complex every day</span>. As you spend more time and resources keeping the network up and running, it gets tough to develop and prepare for <span class="blue"> new markets or products</span>. It’s time to make the switch to managed network services.</p>
<p>Access this white paper to discover the <span class="red">key benefits</span> of managed network services and learn how to stay in control of your network at the same time.</p>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.green {
    color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.red {
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.blue {
    color:blue;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/htb5wmzm/)**

You can use jQuery to mark all "The" words.

```
$.fn.wrapInTag = function(opts) {

  var tag = opts.tag || 'strong',
      words = opts.words || [],
      regex = RegExp(words.join('|'), 'gi'),
      replacement = '<'+ tag +'>$&</'+ tag +'>';

  return this.html(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(regex, replacement);
  });
};

$('ul').wrapInTag({
  tag: 'span class="green" ',
  words: ['the']
});
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/htb5wmzm/1/)

Comment: The OP is aware she can use `span` this way. She is asking whether she can highlight all the "the" words

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a little bit of Javascript/jQuery, then this is how you can do it

I've used Javascript's **RegExp** to search for the word `and` globally.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hold = $('p').html();
  var match = hold.replace(/and/g, "<span>and</span>");
  $('p').html(match);
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is Title 1
Enterprise networks are becoming more complex every day. As you spend more time and resources keeping the network up and running, it gets tough to develop and prepare for new markets or products. It’s time to make the switch to managed network
services.
Access this white paper to discover the key benefits of managed network services and learn how to stay in control of your network at the same time.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to mark exact every "the" - it should be done by javascript (I hardly can suggest other ways.
The logics is as follows:
1. You know that, for example, you need to scan all "

" tags for "the" word using javascript.
2. You wrap it with special span with the class you already have CSS for (where you write the color you need).

If you have editor in your site, that allows you setting special tags (like spans) and set them classes, then you need to set the spans with specific classes on the text you need, and the text will be the color (or whatever preferences) you need.

For example:

```
<p>Enterprise networks are <span class='ColoredRedText'>becoming more complex every day</span>. As you spend more time and resources keeping the network up and running, it gets tough to develop and prepare for new markets or products. It’s time to make the switch to managed network services.</p>
<p>Access this white paper to discover the <span class='ColoredRedText'>key benefits</span> of managed network services and learn how to stay in control of your network at the same time.</p>
```

so then you write CSS:

```
span.ColoredRedText{
color: #b80000;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

and you get what you need.

As for javascript for "the" word, I would better use JQUERY and would do like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('p').each(function(){
$(this).html.replace("the", "<span class='theThe'>the</span>")
});
</script>
```

here is a [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qnva4umd/):
https://jsfiddle.net/qnva4umd/

Hope my many words written here are clear and answer your question.